# How to change chown from mysql console?

Tags: linux, mysql

I have a file `/tmp/test.csv` created by the `mysql` process (`SELECT * INTO OUTFILE`), thus having `mysql:mysql` ownership.

Problem: I'd like to rewrite the chmod from within the mysql console:

```
mysql --user=root --password=rootpw --database=$DB -e "system chown other:other /tmp/test.csv"
```

Result:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/tmp/test.csv': Operation not permitted
```

This is strange because the mysql proces actually owns the file, but why can't it be changed?

Comment: @slhck so you're actually saying there is no solution to the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` owner problem?

Comment: No, because the MySQL user does not have privileges to chown a file as someone else. You have to do it later on via superuser access.